# Modify raster pixels based on another raster layer

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator

I have two raster layers. One layer contains the data of the first day a pixel experiences degrees Celsius above a certain threshold. The other layer contains hotspots in Iceland. These hotspots always meet this threshold condition so they skew the data in the first layer.

Therefore, I would like to set the pixels in layer 1 to 0, if they are equal overlap with the hotspots in layer 2.

I tried using the raster calculator in QGIS:

```
"layer1@1" * ("layer2@1" * 0)
```

But this gives me a map only consisting of 0's. I would like to only set the values within the raster pixels of layer 2 to 0 in layer 1.

How can I do that with the raster calculator?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to delete the pixels (set to NoData) or set them to 0?

Comment: Yes, I would like to set them to 0 in layer 1, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

While `Raster Calculator` does not explicitly implement `IF/THEN` control statements, you can use a workaround like this:

`("layer2@1" = 0) * "layer1@1"`

where `("layer2@1" = 0)` can be either `0` or `1`.
It then gets multiplied by the value of `layer1@1`.

Maybe I am not quite clear about the exact logic you are trying to accomplish (i.e how you want layer1 and/or layer2 to behave), but the idea should be applicable.

Another interpretation of your question/need could be solved with just:

`("layer2@1" = "layer1@1") * 0`

which sets the pixel to `0` if `layer1@1` has the same value as `layer2@1`.

Comment: That's what I was going to respond, so I suppose this is the way to do. By the way, @Thomas: You used two multiplications, where one of the three multipliers is a 0 - that of course always returns 0.

Comment: Correct: thanks for pointing out the reason why the result was 0 everywhere.